# How can i have callable tuple property?

Tags: typescript, tuples

I have the following function

```
function test(cb: Function | number) {
  let item = { height: 0}
  if(typeof cb === 'number') {
    item.height = cb;
  }
  if(typeof cb === 'object') {
    item.height = cb();
  }
}
```

so i am passing dynamic property - it will be either a number or Function
i am checking if it is a number then initialise directly if it is a function then
i am calling the function which i send as a callback and it will return a number

```
function getNumber() {
   return 2;
}

test(getNumber);
```

i keep getting the error when i try   `item.height = cb();`

```
 No constituent of type 'number | Function' is callable.
```

How can i solve ?
I don't want to use any here - if i use `any` the error will be gobe but it is not a nice solution.

Comment: Where is the tuple in this question?  Do you mean “union” instead?

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this error in ts playground, but try to change `typeof cb === 'object'` to `cb instanceof Function` and `Function | number` to `() => number | number`.

Comment: @Please try again - i edited the question -

Comment: When i try () => number | number => i get () =>Function type notation must be parenthesized when used in a union type.

Comment: What version of typescript are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
function test(cb: Function | number) {
  let item = { height: 0}
  if(typeof cb === 'number') {
    item.height = cb;
  }
  if(typeof cb === 'function') {
    item.height = cb();
  }
}

function getNumber() {
   return 2;
}

test(getNumber);
```

Check if `cb` is a `function`, not an `object`. This way TypeScript understands that `cb` in that case is callable.

Comment: thank you that fixed my issue. I thought it shpuld work because function is a object it self also but obviously it needs more explicit tell that we search for function

Answer (score 0):

A few key points to make this work smoothly:

1. You actually don't need to explicitly check for both possibilities of the union since there are  only two cases.
2. Use more specific function type than `Function` thereby requiring that the caller pass a function that takes no parametera and returns a `number`. This type is written `() => number`.

   ```
   function test(cb: (() => number) | number) {
      const item = { height: 0 };
      if (typeof cb === 'number') {
          // cb is `number` here
          item.height = cb;
      }
      else {
          // cb is `() => number` here, by elimination
          item.height = cb();
      }
   }
   ```